# Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have this code:

```
IList<Type> lista = new List<Type>();
lista.Add(typeof(Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeEntry));

using (FileStream writer = new FileStream("c:/temp/file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(videoContainer.GetType(), lista);
    ser.WriteObject(writer, videoContainer);
}
```

which generates to me this Exception: `Type 'Google.GData.Client.AtomUri' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.`

I can't edit `Google.GData.Client.AtomUri` adding those attributes (it's a Library).

So, how can I fix this trouble?

Comment: What is unclear in the message?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I cannot edit a DLL adding those attributes... this means "I cannot serialize" that object?

Comment: it means that *it* cannot (or will not), without more information / confidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're going after is the values of the properties, you can use basic reflection and display them. This will show all the property values, including iterating through collections, for a given object. Not the best code in the world, but a nice quick and dirty solution for reading an object.

```
static void ShowProperties(object o, int indent = 0)
{
    foreach (var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", string.Empty.PadRight(indent), prop.Name);
            var coll = (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(o, null);
            if (coll != null)
            {
                foreach (object sub in coll)
                {
                    ShowProperties(sub, indent + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", string.Empty.PadRight(indent), prop.Name, prop.GetValue(o, null));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}------------", string.Empty.PadRight(indent));
}
```

Comment: I get an `System.FormatException` on `Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", string.Empty.PadRight(indent), prop.Name, prop.GetValue(o, null));`

Comment: Don't know - must be something weird on one of the properties. You can try wrapping a `try/catch` inside the `foreach` loop, and just ignore the errors. Or dig a little deeper into what's actually throwing that exception - the `Console` call wouldn't be the one, so it's probably something inside the property itself.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't edit Google.GData.Client.AtomUri adding those attributes (it's a Library).

Then you have two choices:

- write a separate DTO layer which *is* serializable; this is usually trivial, and is almost always my preferred route when hitting a problem with ***any*** serializer. Meaning: write your own set of types that look broadly similar to the `GData` classes, which are decorated and constructed in a way suitable for your chosen serializer - and write a handful of lines of code to map between them
- use one of the multiple overloads to the `DataContractSerializer` constructor to specify additional information; frankly this usually just gets you into a fiddly maze of telling it more and more in awkward code until it *just about works*; the DTO is much more maintainable

Comment: That's crazy! The object is so "huge/deep".

Comment: @markzzz then perhaps consider whether a different serializer might be a better option. Would `XmlSerializer` work? that often doesn't require any configuration whatsoever.

Comment: Tried right now: `Google.GData.Client.AtomUri cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.`

Comment: @markzzz does it need to be xml, specifically? Re `DataContractSerializer` - you could *try* faffing with the constructor options to configure it, but I restate my warning: that can be a major pain.

Comment: My problem is this: I have to understand which Field store a value inside the object, because I can't find the location also reading the documentation. So, I'd like to print all values/field as XML and find it with a "search string", understanding what is the property I need, and where it is. Tried JavascriptSerialization, QuickView on debugging, ObjectDumper... but seems that I cannot serialize it. What can you suggest to me?

Comment: @markzzz for what you are trying to do there? field-based reflection

Comment: Uhm? Have you got a simple example?